# How to send array of integers from C++ to tcl?

Tags: c++, tcl

I tried passing one element to TCL. That worked fine. But when I tried the same for vectors(dynamic arrays in C++). It gives error that no knowing procedure to converts vectors to int*. In fact i want to pass a vector of vectors. How to do this?

Comment: Are you using SWIG for this? If so, please add that to the question's tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a pointer out of a C++ std::vector by using its `.data()` method:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int* arr = vec.data();
```